# joins and querying in sqlalchamy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a database relationship of bans and accounts. One account can have multiple bans.  My classes look like this:

```
class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = "accounts"

    _accountId = Column(Integer, name="accountId", primary_key=True)
    _username = Column(String, name="username")
    _password = Column(String, name="password")
    _salt = Column(String, name="salt")
    _lastLoggedIn = Column(String, name="lastLoggedIn")
    _banned = relationship("Banned")

class Banned(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bannedAccounts'
    _id = Column(Integer, name="Id", primary_key=True)
    _accountId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('accounts.accountId'), name="accountId")
    _reason = Column(String, name="Reason")
    _expires = Column(String, name="Expires")
```

I am trying to do a query which involves select all accounts with a username and joining it up to the banned table to see if they have any bans.  My code currently looks like this:

```
engine = create_engine(self.connectionString)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

query = session.query(Account, Banned)
query = query.filter(Account._username == self.username).filter(Account._accountId == Banned._accountId).all()
```

my problem is that it will return a tuple of accounts and their associated bans that match `self.username` as long as they have some bans.  However, if they do not have any bans rather then getting account objects returned I get `None` returned.  Is there anyway to fix this?

Edit
the end point I want to get to in sql is this

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN bannedaccounts
ON accounts.accountId = bannedaccounts.AccountID
WHERE username= self.username
```

Comment: What is the SQL that is being generated currently? What is the SQL you are expecting to create with your query?

Comment: How can I check what the sql is thats being generated? isn't the point of an orm to abstract away from generating sql? I've editted the first post with what I am aiming for in the sql. I believe I've found the problem in that its doing a normal join rather then a left join. However I can't seem to work out how to tell it to do a left join when I'm making the relation

Comment: You must [enable SQLAlchemy logging](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/engines.html#dbengine-logging). While the "point" of an ORM probably dabbles somewhere in the idea of "abstracting the database", the fact is that is that it [cannot do that perfectly](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html). My question regarding the SQL generated was slightly rhetorical; when debugging any ORM, you're going to have to dig into the SQL. It could be argued, then, that the "point" of an ORM is all the stuff it does BESIDES complex SQL generation.

Comment: I'll also point to an article from SQLAlchemy primary developer Mike Bayer), where he says "[SQLAlchemy isn't in the business of building an opaque abstraction layer for you. Its just providing the richest zone of overlap between the two idioms as it possibly can so that you can build the best abstraction for your needs.](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2007/05/29/polymorphic-associations-with-sqlalchemy/)"

Comment: yup as expected (after looking at the logs) the problem is that the ORM is doing a inner join rather then a left join. So if there is nothing in the banned account table we are going be returned nothing. Thanks Mark thats at least put me on the right path (and also demonstrated that you can't just rely on a orm to do everything for you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem as identified once I turned on logging is that by default SQLAlchamy does an inner join (while I wanted a left join). To Solve this we can change the query to this

```
    query = session.query(Account, Banned).outerjoin(Banned)
    query = query.filter(Account._username == self.username).all()
```

Comment: I also should mention that the query object itself converts to the SQL string when you convert it to a string. So, if you left off the `all()`, and printed the resulting `query` you could also see the SQL query generated. The `all()` is what actually causes the query to be run on the database.